# How to display multiple videos in single view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I tried to display more than one vide in single frame using the following code

```
NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath1=[bundle pathForResource:@"tom1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieUrl1=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath1];
MPMoviePlayerController *movie1=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieUrl1];
movie1.view.frame=CGRectMake(15, 15, 80, 80);

[videoScrollViewObj addSubview:movie1.view];


NSBundle *bundle1=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath2=[bundle1 pathForResource:@"tom2" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieUrl2=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath2];
MPMoviePlayerController *movie2=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieUrl2];
movie2.view.frame=CGRectMake(15, 110, 80, 80);
[videoScrollViewObj addSubview:movie2.view];'
```

but i am getting only last video.

Can anyone tell me how to display more than one video in a single view. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Because documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects
>   and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a
>   time can play its movie.

Answer (score 0):

As beryllium said - it's not possible using Apple's existing views

You could try to implement your own player that grabs frames from a file and displays them into a view.